# Looping with Object Literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Alert:** shameless homework help.

I am trying to create an amortization schedule for paying off a credit card. I'm stuck because I think I need to create a loop that does all the calculations until the credit card balance is zero. I know basic loops, I know basic objects; and, referencing a different function (aka not local function) for the payment id. Combining the principles is baffling me atm.

Full problem details commented out in code.

Ive tried messing around with different loop ideas; after I'm asking for loop help, i think. I cant get the loop to work, it usually ends up being infinite and crashing the browser. But in relation to above criteria confuses me a bit.

```
function displayWelcome() {
  printLine();
  console.log('Welcome to the credit card payoff tool.');
  printLine();
  console.log('This program will determine the time it \nwill take to pay off a credit card!');
  printLine();
}
displayWelcome();

function calculateMinimumPayment(balance, interestRate) {    
  var calcMinPay = balance * interestRate; 
  return calcMinPay 
}

function generatePaymentId() {  // lines 14 - 22 are a closure function. 
  var count = 0;
  function paymentId() {
    count ++;           
    return count;
  }
  return paymentId;
};
var id = generatePaymentId();

function processPaymentSchedule(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {
  var year = 1;
  var counter = 0;
  while (balance > counter) {
    var interestDecimal = interest / 100;
    var interestMonthly = interestDecimal / 12;
    var interestPaid = balance * interestMonthly;

    var payment = {
      year: year,
      balance: balance,
      paymentId: id(), 
      interest_paid: interestPaid
    }
    displayPayment(payment);
    balance = balance - interestPaid;    
    return balance;         
  }   
}

function displayPayment(payment) {
  console.log(payment.year);  
}
printLine();
function printLine() {
  console.log('---------------------------------------');
}
printLine();
processPaymentSchedule(1500,18, calculateMinimumPayment());

/*
It should take the balance monthly interest rate and minimum payment as arguments. Each time you calculate a new payment line, create an object literal with properties for the year balance and payment id and interest paid. Pass this object literal to the displayPayment function.
*/
```

Given these numbers
 (balance=1500, interest=18%, minimumPayment(a separate function showing 2% of the balance as minimum payment.))

**Year / Balance / PaymentID / InterestPaid** 
1    1492.50     1        22.50
     1484.89     2        67.16
(continue to till balance is zero)

Comment: Please read [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Help us help you!

Comment: The `minimumPayment` appears to pay no role whatsoever in the payment calculations. On top of that, when you call `calculateMinimumPayment()`, your code does not pass in the two required parameters.

Comment: haha like the alert. Good try. With this question, was there some blank functions given which you had to use? A couple tips so it is easier for others to read, try to group all your functions together (Either all at the bottom or top).

Comment: According to the directions 'generatePaymentId' function didnt need parameters. 'printLine' function was a personal add. It really seems like im setting up the loop wrong and my calculations are off. 

@spangle - thanks for the grouping tip. Only req. empty function I just mentioned, about generate payment id function.